# New pump - Topeak |Pocket Shock

Tags: pump, presta, valves, inflation, topeak

I bought this new pump, but i think I made a mistake.

I need it for my road bikes, with presta valves. I don't understand how I connect the pump to the presta.

Is it even possible?  do I need an adapter?

http://www.topeak.com/products/Pumps/PocketShockDXG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is for adjusting the suspension on a medium to high-end mountain bike (fork), hence the lack of 'Presta' option.

Since you will be returning it, to keep the shop happy and get what you really need, consider getting:

1. A track pump with gauge and aluminium body. Look for one with a well
   engineered head that does Presta and Shrader valves. The easiest
   ones to use have a lever that you fold out to get a snug fit.
2. For the road, carry an affordable, light mini-pump with as few
   movable parts as possible. The deluxe mini-pumps with dual-action,
   fancy gauges and other features have a tendency to rattle apart,
   rendering them useless when you need it.

Keep it simple is what you want with a mini-pump, it only has to get you home and you hopefully will have a proper track pump with gauge at home.

Answer (score 3):

That pump does not appear to be intended for use with tires. Return it and buy an appropriate pump.

Comment: I feared that will be the answer :-/

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it appears to be what it says (though not very clearly) -- a "shock pump", intended for pumping up shocks in bike suspensions, not for pumping up tires.

And, frankly, I've never seen a "mini" pump that could do even a halfway decent job of pumping up high pressure tires.  You need a full-sized frame pump to do it reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, return the Pocket Shock since the intended function is for shocks.  Look into the Topeak Race Rocket HP for a compact road pump.